# Error performing OCR with Tesseract: read_params_file: Can't open deu

Tags: ocr, tesseract

While specifiing the language pack used to perform the OCR, i get the following error (for every language pack corresponding):

```
read_params_file: Can't open deu
```

I used the command as described in the wiki:

```
tesseract test.tif out -1 deu
```

The .traineddata files are located under tessdata and the TESSDATA_PREFIX is set to the parent directory of tessdata. The process works under default without given language information.

I have Tesseract 3.05 installed on Windows 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command should be

```
tesseract test.tif out -l deu
```

with "l" instead of a "1".

Answer (score 2):

This is a common response, if there is anything wrong with your parameter setup. Either if you add a param which is not defined - like "1" or  if you add params in the wrong order.

E.g.

if you add the **hocr** parameter , you have to place it after the -l parameter. In the official docs there is no case in which hocr is used with the language parameter.

Wrong:

```
PS C:\Users\Mememe\Desktop\tesseract> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' 'C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\tesseract\img.jpg' out hocr -l deu
read_params_file: Can't open l
read_params_file: Can't open deu
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
```

Better:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' 'C:\Users\Mememe\Desktop\tesseract\img.jpg' out -l deu hocr
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
```

So if you have this error check:

- Are all your parameters defined? (Check the help parameter to get a list of all available params)
- Are all parameters in the right order? (Good Luck figuring out :) )
- Are the paths I defined correct? Are there dots or spaces I should double check?

If this doesn't work - double check. Otherwise feel free to add your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the os cannot read the command parameters in the tesseract. In cases I have encountered, I have to update the 'locale' on my OS & then:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa: alex-p / tesseract-ocr
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt upgrade

My os is ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04